# Lightweight query server

Tags: linux, service, request

I'm looking for some service server that is extremely simple and lightweight. It's supposed to be used by administration scripts or simple apps to query for information that is available only as root on other server.

I don't need high-throughput, stateful processing, etc. Only blocking, synchronous queries required. Preferably no HTTP server. I'd be happy with something that takes a number of strings as an input and outputs a string over the network. Any data serialisation can be done in the client if required, so that only opaque strings are passed.

Is there any project like that already available? Bindings for perl and python would be a bonus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found RPC::Lite, which satisfies everything (more or less) and is extremely simple to use. I'll probably stick with that, but feel free to add more ideas.

http://metacpan.org/pod/RPC::Lite::Server

Answer (score 0):

There is [D-Bus](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/), but the network transport is a bit... DIY.

Answer (score 0):

So you only need data out of this service?  I have used memcached before to do what it sounds like you need.  There is  Cache::Memcached::Fast in perl that can interface with the process.

Comment: Keep in mind that memcached is lossy, so the result may not actually be in the cache when you need it.

Comment: It's not going to be static, or cache'able data. It's just for stuff like which host handles 'x' right now, how many services 'y' are alive, ... So memcache won't do the trick here.